# How to get bottom records & between records from an object

Tags: soql

I am trying to take backup of a table which contains 1,472,902 records.
As the data is huge i am trying to split the data into top 500k, middle 500k & bottom 500k records.

I got top 500k records using LIMIT function.

Can someone help me with how to get bottom & between records?

Answer (score 0):

To extract over 1 million records, you should be using the [Bulk API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/api_asynch_introduction_bulk_api.htm#!). The Bulk API efficiently handles enormous queries and provides its own chunking features where required (such as PK Chunking in Bulk API 1.0).